solve a recursion formula using a generating function
I have the following formula for a vector $v_n= \ ^t(a_n, b_n)\in \mathbb R^2$ :
$v_n= Av_{n-1}+ Bv_{n-2}$ for two given matrices $A$ and $B$ in $M_2(\mathbb R)$, and we are given $v_1$ and $v_2$ of course. Is there a way to find the general form of $v_n$ by using a generating function for example?
The issue here is that $M_2(\mathbb R)$ is not a commutative ring.
Otherwise, is there another way to solve this? Say that $A$ and $B$ are not simple enough to find easy manipulation. In particular they are not nilpotent.
Is there a cononical method for this?

You can use the same idea for converting a second-order recurrence into a first-order matrix recurrence here; consider $w_n = (v_n, v_{n+1}) = (a_n, b_n, a_{n+1}, b_{n+1})$ and write down a first-order recurrence for it.

I tried it but the problem is that the 4 by 4 matrices now are more complicated to handle, and to add to my context, I am dealing with matrices of polynomials, meaning in $M_2(\mathbb R[x])$

For  $Z\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $Z^2=AZ+B$ we have $$Z^n=AZ^{n-1}+BZ^{n-2},\quad  n\ge 2$$ For $$Z^n=\begin{pmatrix} a_n &*\\ b_n&*\end{pmatrix}$$ the sequence $v_n= \, ^t(a_n,b_n)$ satisfies the recurrence relation. Given $Z$ calculating $Z^n$ can be unpleasent. However there is $U$ such that $\widetilde{Z}=U^{-1}ZU$ is upper triangular, or diagonal if the eigenvalues of $Z$ are different. Then
$$\widetilde{Z}^n=\widetilde{A}\widetilde{Z}^{n-1}+\widetilde{B}\widetilde{Z}^{n-2}$$
